# Java Arrays - What are they

Tags: java, arrays

From looking at the Java Collections API i see that arrays are not regarded as collections.
If not what are arrays regarded as?

Comment: Arrays are regarded as arrays, no?

Comment: Reference arrays are considered implementation details for the most part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arrays are "special" in Java - they don't implement any interfaces, which means they can't implement the collection interfaces. They're collections in "natural language" terms, and you can use the enhanced for loop over them - but if you want to use an array within the collection API, you'll need something like [`Arrays.asList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) which wraps an array with the `List<T>` interface. (The result is only a *view* on the array - changes to the array are visible through the list, and vice versa.)

(This is in contrast to .NET, where `T[]` implements `IList<T>` etc.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, thats a nice helpful answer. Its something i never really thought about before, but im preparing a presentation on some collection topics. I want to be prepared if and when i get asked about arrays. Thanks Jon

Comment: Note that you can change elements through the List, but you cannot add new elements to it, because the backing array cannot grow. You'll get a runtime error if you try.